# How to click an element of div class?

Tags: css, angularjs, robotframework

I am trying to click on the element using robot framework. the HTML code is as below.

**One field:**

```
<div ng-repeat="subCategory in allCategory[searchcategoryIndex].subCategory" 
  class="margin5 ng-scope" ng-click="searchselectSubCategory($index, subCategory.subCatName)" 
  ng-class="{selectedcategory : searchsubCategoryIndex == $index}" style="">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 padding0 ng-binding" ng-bind="subCategory.subCatName" data-dismiss="modal">Murrah</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**Second field**

```
<div ng-repeat="subCategory in allCategory[searchcategoryIndex].subCategory" 
  class="margin5 ng-scope" ng-click="searchselectSubCategory($index, subCategory.subCatName)" 
  ng-class="{selectedcategory : searchsubCategoryIndex == $index}">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 padding0 ng-binding" ng-bind="subCategory.subCatName" data-dismiss="modal">Surti</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I am not able to see more difference in this fields. I have around 10 similar fields. How can I select the field? I just want to click on specific field.

So far I have tried below statements:

```
Click element xpath=//div[@Class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 padding0 ng-binding"] 
Click element xpath=//div[@Class="margin5 ng-scope"] 
Click Link Murrah
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of what you've tried so far.

Comment: So far I have tried below statements.
Click element    xpath=//div[@Class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 padding0 ng-binding"]
Click element    xpath=//div[@Class="margin5 ng-scope"]
Click Link    Murrah

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments. You can [edit]  your question to add additional information.

Comment: are you looking for a way to give each input a unique class/id? and does this id need to be significant?

Comment: There are around 10 elements on the page which is having the properties as mentioned above. I am not sure how should I write the script to click on specific element. I just want to know the script of robot framework to click on specific element. thanks

Comment: What is the distinguishable property of the element you want to locate - is it the texts "Murrah", "Surti", etc? Which element do you want to click - that one, or the parent `div`?

Comment: Yes exactly I am looking for the element murrah and surti to be clicked.